# ERROR loading files on wxMaxima [iMac]

Tags: maxima

I hope you can solve this or at least tell what to do about it because I'm clueless. The thing is that once I've saved a `.wxm` file and then want to open it appears on wxMaxima this error and the "app" crashes:

```
Maxima encountered a Lisp error:
decoding error on stream

<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "socket 127.0.0.1:62607, peer: 127.0.0.1:4011"

{13F30991}
(:EXTERNAL-FORMAT :ASCII):
the octet sequence (195) cannot be decoded.

Automatically continuing.
To enable the Lisp debugger set debugger-hook to nil.
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I run the latest Mac OS X version on my iMac.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file and write it down.

```
(setf sb-impl::*default-external-format* :utf-8)
(setf sb-alien::*default-c-string-external-format* :utf-8)
```

Save the file as **.sbclrc** at Home (User) folder.

Comment: I did this with TextEdit and, since I only name it with that extension, the file got hidden. The problem persists.

Comment: Check the file to follow below procedures.
(1) Launch Terminall.app.
(2) Put 'cd ~/' (except '), and hit return key.
(3) Set 'ls -a | grep "^\."' (except '), and do.
Then, the list of ".xxxxx" will be shown.
(4) Look for ".sbclrc" in the list.
If you save the file as the correct name, the name must be listed.

Comment: It is listed as .sbclrc.rtf

Comment: Then, enter these commands. `cd ~/` and `mv .sbclrc.rtf .sbclc`. Try to open your file as .wxm on wxMaxima. It may work without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I come back on this post as I have been affected by this today.
I am using Ubunutu 14.04 and the same bug appears. To me it is due to Maxima not being able to load anything else than ".mac" files, nothing to do with utf-8/ASCII (I have mv a file that is working to a wxm and vice-versa, it will not work anymore / rework)

Also I have prepared a workaround:
The idea is too have a tool that translates your .wxm files to a .mac file just before you load it (it is actually a very easy bash script)

So: 
you put the [wxm-to-mac.sh](https://github.com/renn0xtek9/wxm-to-mac/tree/master) files into your path

then inside maxima, instead of doing

```
load("foo.wxm")
```

you simply do

```
system("wxm-to-mac foo.wxm")$
load("foo.mac")$
```

Bare in mind you shall not edit the foo.mac file because a routine might re-erase it afterward. Instead keep editing the .wxm file.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file has been saved with some non-ASCII characters (e.g. UTF-8) in it, but it is not read as UTF-8; that seems to be a bug in wxMaxima. Can you please post the offending .wxm file?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the lateness. I'm kind of a noob on this so... How can I upload the file?

Comment: @user2851466 Looks like stackoverflow doesn't allow attachments. How about uploading it to pastebin.com.

Comment: @user2851466 Thanks for the link. I see that there are some non-ASCII characters in the document, such as u with an acute accent. Couple of ideas. (1) As a work-around, you can edit the file in a text editor (it is actually OK to do so) and substitute ASCII characters for non-ASCII, then try loading it again. (2) Maybe there is some way to tell wxMaxima that you are using UTF-8 characters. (I tried loading the file and it works OK for me; I guess that on my system, UTF-8 is the default, or something.) You can try editing the wxMaxima configuration (Edit menu >> Configure) to set the language.

Comment: @user2851466 Maybe try posting a message to the wxMaxima project. Be sure to include a pointer to the pastebin stuff. See: https://sourceforge.net/p/wxmaxima/discussion/

Comment: I've tried both things, setting the language and this: http://sourceforge.net/p/wxmaxima/discussion/435775/thread/ee9923cd/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, since none here could give a straight and correct answer (at least is not marked with the green icon) i tried to look somewhere else. I couldn't find an answer that solve my problem, but then i thought that i had used WxMaxima on Mac before and it worked pretty nice. The last time i installed wxmaxima on mac and it worked was in september 2012, i went to the http://sourceforge.net website and searched for the maxima file that was available on that date and i found http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-MacOS/5.18.1-MacOS/, i installed it and its working pretty fine (about the problem, it is weird, even if i create a new maxima file typed "a" and saved it, i could no longer open it, so i'm guessing that it has nothing to do with ascii or non-ascii characters) I have no idea why this error happens on the recent version of Maxima/WxMaxima, but it makes no sense that we have to install a previous version for it to work.
Anyway, it's working for me, and i hope it works for you too. Glad i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case, the name of the directory where the ".wxm" file is located, contained Korean letter.  I changed the directory name with an English one.
Then the problem has been solved.
I hope this works for you, too.